# "if lt IE 9" equivalent in PHP?

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

Is there an equivalent in PHP for the HTML Syntax:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="/js/html5/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

?

Comment: Generally speaking, it isn't useful to do browser detection on the server side, what is your usecase?

Comment: We want to add JS Code depending on the IE version, and as our framework has its own way of including javascript files and js code, I want to avoid putting the above lines in our header template and instead add it on the server side.

Comment: Doing this client side with conditional comments is the most reliable way. It would be better to use feature detection instead of browser detection though.

Comment: The JS's have feature detection in them and won't do anything if the browser has native support, so I could just add them to the document, but I think its better to generally check if I actually need to add them (by checking if it's lt IE9)... What's the more recommended way? Add the conditional comments to our HTML and ignore our programming standards or to just include them, no matter what browser the user has?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use native php function [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-browser.php);

And read this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/23/introducing-ie9-s-user-agent-string.aspx). Try this code:

```
    $browser = get_browser();

    switch ($browser->browser) {
        case "IE":
            switch ($browser->majorver) {
                case 6:
                case 5:
                    echo '<link href="ie5plus.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
                    break;
                case 9:
                    echo '<link href="ie5plus.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
                    break;
                default:
                    echo '<link href="ieold.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
            }

            break;
}
```

Comment: approving this answer because it answers the question, even though I've solved the problem on another way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do User Agent detection in PHP manually using `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`, or you can use a ready-made solution such as [`get_browser`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) (which admittedly is kind of a hassle to set up).

However, usually there's not so much to be gained from doing this on the server (although there are legitimate cases, I 've needed to do this myself). Perhaps you can achieve the aim on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

Read about [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php) opportunities. Specifically, `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. You can also detect the browser using Javascript and send it to Your server-side PHP code using AJAX

Comment: if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false) detects if it's IE. But how to check if its lower than IE9?

Comment: That's why client side detection is better.